# Getdate() function does not work in SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, getdate

I am a newbie to programming. I downloaded the free version of SQL Server 2014, the Express edition. Somehow the `Getdate()` function is not working. It says

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

If I just say `GETDATE`. It says

> Could not find stored procedure 'GETDATE'.

Can someone tell me if some library is missing from my installation?

I tried reinstalling the software assuming that some libraries were missing.

`getdate()` is what I am trying. Even the `Datepart()` and any of the date functions does not work.

Could you please help me to resolve the above issues and guide on the correct syntax?

Comment: `SELECT GETDATE()` - function call or `DECLARE @v DATETIME = GETDATE()`

Comment: You should consider deleting this question. Since it is just typo it is not going to help anybody in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To do it work you need to add `select`.

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Comment: Oh I am an idiot! Thanks for your lightning fast reply.

Answer (score 1):

`GETDATE()` is a `function`, you need to close the parentheses and add `SELECT` clause.

Type `SELECT GETDATE();`

And check the oficial docs: [GETDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)